# What is the purpose of adding features vector to the output of neural network layer before feeding it to the next layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

Let's assume our neural network is made from two functions f(x) and g(x). They could be something simple like f(x) = ReLu(W1 * x + b1) and g(x) = Softmax(W2 * x + b2). Of course most of the time they are much more complicated, like for example chain of nested LSTMs, but this is irrelevant to my question.

Simplest way of stacking them together is just feeding output of layer f to layer g, so our network would looks like Y^ = g(f(X)), where X is our features vector and Y^ is vector of predicted labels.

But after checking more advanced examples, I noticed authors are making slightly different stack, where they add original features vector to output of the middle layers, so network looks then this way Y^ = g(X + f(X)).

Could somebody explain to me what is the purpose of this? What is the advantage of using X + f(X) instead of just f(x)?

Comment: Can you provide a cite for an article where you've seen this?

Answer (score 1):

this is what called the residual network.

say normally the output of some layer is $y=h(x)$, instead of letting $h(x)$ learn the output directly, the residual network learns another function $f(x)$, which is supposed to be the difference between the input $x$ and the output $h(x)$. Or equivalently $f(x) = h(x)-x$, so $h(x) = f(x)+x$ should be used as the "true" output.

In the residual network paper, the author built a 100-layer (even 1000-layer) network, and showed very good results.

reference: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385v1.pdf